# Netbeans IDE: Unknown error when running a Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, netbeans

Ok, I am having a real painful issue on Netbeans IDE 8.0. I have already installed Android SDK, GIT, Cordova and Node.js.

However, I tried to test an index.html sample page by clicking on "Run" above, and I got an unknown error (Refer to the attached screenshot [here](http://postimg.org/image/exxsscobx/)).

Why is this? Thank!